# Creating new TFS 2010 project with VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is it true that there's no way for Visual Studio 2008 to create a new project on Team Foundation Server 2010?

I've managed to make VS2008 connect to my TFS2010 server (the team explorer + sp1 + forward compatibility thing), and yeap, I can see my TFS2010 collections from the VS2008 UI itself.

**Problem is**, I can't seem to find a way to create a new team project on the TFS2010 server through the VS2008 UI. Can't create from scratch, can't add existing projects to source.

If VS2008 *really* can't do this with TFS2010 (frustrating!!), what alternatives do I have? I'd hate to have to boot up VS2010 just to create new projects everytime.

*(and yes, I somehow have my reasons why I'm still stuck on my VS2008 when I have a VS2010 install. sucks to be me. :( )*

Thanks guys.

Comment: How often do you create new Team Projects?  For the amount of effort, and the frequency, it seems like starting an instance of VS2010 shouldn't be that big of a deal.

Comment: Well, actually, if it was just me, I'd be willing to cope with the infrequent VS2010 bootups from time to time. However, I'm more concerned on a team scale; so a whole plethora of developers would have to be knocking on the [server admins'] doors everytime a new project had to be put up.

Just thinking that it could get a bit impractical then. I'd prefer a more solid solution, rather than what feels like a workaround, if you get what I mean. :D

Comment: We significantly restrict team project creation to only a small handful of SCM administrators.  I'd hate to see an environment where a whole plethora of developers has the ability to create team projects both willy and nilly.  It would get out of control quickly, I believe.

Comment: Exactly. Don't get me wrong, we do have admins for the role, but they're not the ones that are in direct communication with the clients: the Project Managers do, and in turn, the Tech Leads, who greatly outnumber admins, definitely.

Thing is, the admins also develop to some extent, which explains the VS2008 instance. I guess it all boils down to whether or not everyone should upgrade to VS2010, and have it all over with. :) It's just a nice thought, being able to do our old job with the current VS we have. If we can't have that, then well, we've just havta suck it up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little [googling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/teams_wit_tools/compatibility-matrix-for-2010-beta-2-team-foundation-server-to-team-explorer-2008-and-2005) found this on MSDN:

> As Team Explorer 2008 and Team Explorer 2005 are not aware of several Team Foundation Server 2010 features, administrative functionality has been limited to the Team Explorer 2010 client. For example, the administrator can only run the Project Creation Wizard from Team Explorer 2010 to add Team Project to Team Foundation Server 2010. Team Explorer 2010 client can also be used to administer the Team Foundation Server 2008 server

But you can down load [Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FE4F9904-0480-4C9D-A264-02FEDD78AB38&displaylang=en) its a stand alone TFS UI but it wont work if you have VS 2010 installed.

Comment: Was afraid of that, but not at all surprised. Thanks, I'll try that out!

Comment: Its basically a VS 2010 that has no functionality besides Team Explorer.