# Unable to add Project to TFS 2010 collection from Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have windows 7 64 Bit Computer

I have the following:

- Visual Studio 2008 Professional:
- Install Team Explorer 2008
- Install SP for Visual Studio 2008
- update Team Explorer 2008 SP1 Forward Compatibility Update

But it didn't work.

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of error/s you are getting?  It is hard to help without any information.

Answer (score 0):

You need VS 2010 (or team explorer 2010) to create new team projects in TFS 2010.

See [Creating new TFS 2010 project with VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047145/creating-new-tfs-2010-project-with-vs-2008) for a previous question on this.

Comment: If i make a new Team Projekt: TF30172: You are trying to create a team project either without required permissions or with an older version of Team Explorer. Contact your project administrator to check your permissions or to derermine how to upgrade Team Explorer.

Comment: Or if I add a new Project to the TFS: Visual Studio Team System: No team project source control folders are available.